# Error starting Sonar

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarqube

I'm using SONAR for my project. 
While using "StartSonar.bat" for launch of Sonar, it is throwing the following exception.

```
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Error occurred during initialization of VM
jvm 1    | java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 2    | Error occurred during initialization of VM
jvm 2    | java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 3    | Error occurred during initialization of VM
jvm 3    | java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 4    | Error occurred during initialization of VM
jvm 4    | java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 5    | Error occurred during initialization of VM
jvm 5    | java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
wrapper  | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.    
Giving up.
wrapper  |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Using Java 1.7.0._09. Please help me in getting out of this.
Also, I tried configuring Sonar in IntelliJ IDEA 11 Community Edition. It fails in the startup of IDE. Are any plugins available for Community Edition to run Sonar.

Comment: The same I encounter in two more systems after upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

what value do you have for the 'wrapper.java.command' in the wrapper.conf file? Seems like the  is no JVM available

Comment: I'm using Windows machine and I did not set 'wrapper.java.command'. I have tried after setting the environment variable even, still it is same. By default it takes from 'JAVA_HOME' I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have installed a JDK, and not just the JRE?

Also Check JAVA_HOME is configured correctly. Make sure to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the JDK root folder.

Comment: I have executed SONAR when I have JDK 1.7.0 in my machine. I have updated JDK to  1.7.0_09 version and not able to execute SONAR

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing, go to `<sonarDirectory>\conf` and edit the `wrapper.conf` file and set these 2 lines:

```
wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\java
#wrapper.java.command=java
```